# JSF @Named Target Unreachable, identifier '*bean*' resolved to null

Tags: jsf

I checked there are many other threads with similar issues but i cannot find what's wrong with this one. The CDI @Named doesn't conflict with @ManagedBean.
This is the bean class i'm using.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class UserBean {

    private String name;

    public UserBean() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String addValuesToFlashAction() {
        Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getFlash();
        flash.put("name", name);
        return "terms?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public void pullValuesFromFlashAction(ComponentSystemEvent e) {
        Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getFlash();
        this.name = (String) flash.get(name);
    }
...
}
```

And this is the body of the xhtml index page

```
<h:body>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event type="preRenderView"
                 listener="#{userBean.pullValuesFromFlashAction}"/>
    </f:metadata>
    <h:messages/>
    <h:form>
        Name: <h:inputText value="#{userBean.name}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="Register" 
                         action="#{userBean.addValuesToFlashAction()}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

When i run this i have **/flashIndex.xhtml @12,72 listener="#{userBean.pullValuesFromFlashAction}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'userBean' resolved to null** and in glassfish logs it throws a **javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException**

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:
i imported **javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped** instead of **javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped**